# Resize a char array when you search a word in this one?

Tags: c++, arrays, search, char

I'm trying to resize a char array (with a search algorithm) like that:

```
char* items[] = { "apple", "apple_2", "banana", "orange" };
```

and with that when I'm searching for example "app", "appl", "pple" I want to have a resize of the char array like that:

```
char* items[] = { "apple", "apple_2" };
```

With only the word(s) which contains "app", "appl" for example, if I search "a" my char array don't move because all words in my example contain a "a";

I'm not sure if I'm really clear. Thx in advance for your help ! And sorry for my english !

Comment: C++ does not work this way. Arrays have a fixed size, defined at compile-time.

Comment: static one at least you can still use new to change size but i'm not sure what you want to do

Comment: So if I can't resize this array I can create an other which take the good size when I have searched the word that I want ?

Comment: In `c++` you do this with `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: Okay I'm going to try that thx !

Answer (score 0):

Static arrays in C++ cannot be resized in runtime.
To achieve your goal please look at `std::vector` standard container. It can dynamically change it's size.

Here is example, how you can implement your task:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                           
#include <vector>                                                                                                                                                                             

std::vector<std::string> filter(const std::vector<std::string>& strings, const std::string& pattern)                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                                                             
   std::vector<std::string> matchItems;                                                                                                                                                       
   for (const auto& elem : strings)                                                                                                                                                           
   {                                                                                                                                                                                          
       if (elem.find(pattern) != std::string::npos)                                                                                                                                           
       {                                                                                                                                                                                      
           matchItems.push_back(elem);                                                                                                                                                        
       }                                                                                                                                                                                      
   }                                                                                                                                                                                          
   return matchItems;                                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                                             

int main()                                                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                                                             
    std::vector<std::string> v { "apple", "apple_2", "banana", "orange" };                                                                                                                    
    auto filtered = filter(v, "app");                                                                                                                                                         
    for (const auto& elem : filtered)                                                                                                                                                         
    {                                                                                                                                                                                         
        std::cout << elem << " ";                                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                                         

    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

What's more, using raw `char*` and arrays is quite old-style.
In modern C++ you should rather use `std::string, std::vector, std::array`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a very good reason for using an array of `char *` (if there is, please indicate that reason and I will try to accommodate it in my answer) you should try to use the features of the language.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> items{ "apple", "apple_2", "banana", "orange" };

    std::string test_value{"app"};
    auto new_end = std::remove_if(items.begin(), items.end(),
                                  [&test_value](auto idx)->auto {
                                      return idx.find(test_value) == std::string::npos;
                                  });

    items.erase(new_end, items.end());

    return 0;
}
```

First we use `std::vector<std::string>` to store the values. As has been pointed out resizing an array is problematic. Then using a defined `test_value` the STL library function `std::remove_if` and a lambda we can gather the desired value to the beginning of the `vector`. Then `items.erase()` truncates the vector.

To leave the original `items` untouched:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> items{ "apple", "apple_2", "banana", "green apple", "orange" };

    std::string test_value{"app"};
    std::vector<std::string> selected_items;
    std::copy_if(items.begin(), items.end(), std::back_inserter(selected_items),
                 [&test_value](auto idx)->auto {
                     return idx.find(test_value) != std::string::npos;
                 });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay this method work perfectly and thx for that, but I have a little problem, how to reset the original items list after doing that ? In bref, when the items list is resized how to go back !

Comment: Oh I think I have founded the solution !

Comment: If you want to keep the original contents there are two ways. One is to not call `items.erase` and just iterate over `items.begin()` to `new_end`. If you want to leave the original `items` the way they are you can use `std::copy_if()`. I will edit in an example.